# Loop over multiple datasets and multiple columns but one missing a variable

Tags: r, function, loops, dictionary, dplyr

I am using multiple datasets (survey-waves) including the same variables that I extract in the following manner.

First I create a function to select the relevant variables:

```
files <- list.files(path = getwd())
tmp <- map(files, read_stata)

extractColumns <- function(x){
  select(x, "var1", "var2", "var3", "var4", "var5", "wt")
}
```

Then I apply the function to all datasets:

```
df <- map(tmp,extractColumns) %>% bind_rows()
```

However, the "wt" variable (the weight) is not present in some iterations of the survey. So I get the following error:

```
 Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `wt` doesn't exist.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Because this variable is not included in all waves, I want the code to create a variable "wt" for the waves that do not have this variable and give all respondents in these waves a value 1.

Comment: `if (!("wt" %in% names(x))) x <- x %>% add_column(wt=1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `dplyr::any_of`:

```
myvars <- c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4", "var5", "wt")

extractColumns <- function(x){
  select(x, any_of(myvars))
}
```